# How do I list instances of a class based on an attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class

I'm sure my question has been asked before, but I can't find an example that relates to this particular problem.

My issue: I want to display chess pieces based on their color. Below is what I have:

```
class Grid(object):
    def __init__(grid, piece, color):

#Example pieces
A1 = Grid("White Rook", "White")
A2 = Grid("White Pawn", "White")
A3 = Grid("  ", "  ")
A4 = Grid("  ", "  ")
A7 = Grid("Black Pawn", "Black")
A8 = Grid("Black Rook", "Black")
```

My two methods that I then use are:

```
def SelectPiece():
    for grid in Grid():
        if grid.color == "White":
            print(f"{grid.piece}")
```

or

```
def SelectPiece():
    selection = Grid(color)
    if selection == "White":
        print(f"{grid.piece}")
```

I've tried various other methods, but the message more often than not is "type object 'Grid' has no attribute 'color'". So how can I list the names of pieces based on their attribute of what color they are?

Edit: My apologies as I may update the code quite a bit to better reflect what I have.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show a *complete* example of the *actual* code - it should at least compile. The example you're showing doesn't even have the `:` after `def __init__(grid, piece, color)`, nor a body for that method. Please also show [complete, exact error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough), and make sure each error message you show is correlated correctly with a code example that produces it. We can only tell you what is wrong with things that we can actually see.

Comment: That said, it seems like you fundamentally misunderstand how classes work. In particular, it seems like you somehow expect that `for grid in Grid():` will iterate over... what, exactly? Every `Grid` instance that you every previously created? If you want to iterate over a bunch of values, you have to make a sequence that contains those values. It's no different from if you had integers or strings. (Also, if this class is supposed to represent *a chess piece*, then why is it named `Grid` rather than, for example, `Piece`?)

Comment: I suspect that you need help that is outside the scope of a single Stack Overflow question, due to a general confusion about how to use classes. Stack Overflow is *not a discussion forum* nor a tutorial center; you should probably try Reddit or Quora.

Comment: So I'm just straight up using the class function incorrectly? If so, I'll take a different approach.

Comment: Please just try to follow a tutorial and work through someone else's example of a class that does something useful, before trying to design one yourself. Also work through using lists and other sequence types, etc. Also, "the class function" doesn't make sense.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Grid(object):
    def __init__(self, piece, colour):
        self.piece = piece
        self.colour = colour
        

#Example pieces
A1 = Grid("White Rook", "White")
A2 = Grid("White Pawn", "White")
A3 = Grid("  ", "  ")
A4 = Grid("  ", "  ")
A7 = Grid("Black Pawn", "Black")
A8 = Grid("Black Rook", "Black")

pieces = [A1, A2, A3, A4, A7, A8]

white_pieces = []
black_pieces = []

for i in pieces:
    if i.colour == "White":
        white_pieces.append(i.piece)
    elif i.colour == "Black":
        black_pieces.append(i.piece)
        
print(white_pieces)
print(black_pieces)
```

I think this will work.